# custom filtering not working in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, lookup, django-filter

i have tried to use custom filtering by defining a filter class and importing in my view but it is not working.

My code:

```
class ProductAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]  
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

My filter:

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   variants__price = filters.RangeFilter()

   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = ['brand__name','variants__price','availability','slug','category__name',
                       'services','featured','best_seller','top_rated']
```

My models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Product(models.Model):
    
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    mini_category = models.ForeignKey(Minicategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is product featured?
```

Now when I call `localhost/api/products?brand___name__in=lg,sony` it doenst filter and shows all the objects from the database. It only works when I dont put in like this `localhost/api/products?brand___name=lg` .But I need to query through multiple parameters. What is the issue here?? From the docs, it says i can multiple query using __in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default `lookup_expr` is `exact` if you don't describe one.

Your FilterSet should look like this:

```py
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   variants__price = filters.RangeFilter()

   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = {
        'brand__name': ['exact', 'in'],
        'variants__price': ['exact'],
        'availability': ['exact'],
        'slug': ['exact'],
        'category__name': ['exact'],
        'services': ['exact'],
        'featured': ['exact'],
        'best_seller': ['exact'],
        'top_rated': ['exact']
      }
```

Comment: Hello @Keoni..thanks for your answer..But my vairants__price is a range, so should i keep ti exact fot the price or change to something?

Comment: The RangeFilter acts completely differently. You should leave it as exact AFAIK

Comment: But WHERE should the `ProductFilter` be placed? WHERE the `filters`comes from?